# How can you have multiple paragraphs in a ScrollView? XML

Tags: android

I am trying to simply put a few paragraphs on the screen with xml that you can scroll through vertically because they are too big to see them all. I have tried many different things but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding on to what John said above. You want a linearlayout inside a scrollview to achieve this.

Something like the following:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">
       <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="Paragraph 1\n\nParagraph2\n\nParagraph 3"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also, posting what you've tried so far will allow us to help you much better. Help us help you!

Answer (score 1):

Embed the textviews within a linear layout, and give them some padding on the top and bottom.  Either that, or combine the text into one text string and separate them with `\n`.

If you're trying to add multiple textviews into one scrollview, it wont work.  A scrollview container can only have one child, which is why you need to put the textviews into a linear layout, then place that linear layout into the scrollview.

Example:

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
      <TextView text=R.string.MyText1 />
      <TextView text=R.string.MyText2 />
      <TextView text=R.string.MyText3 />
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The `R.string.MyText` will be your paragraphs all copied and pasted into your string resource file with the keys "MyText1", "MyText2", "MyText3", etc.

Comment: What do you mean by paragraphs?  How are you trying to place them now? If you want help, you need to give a better explanation of your problem, maybe post some code with what you're trying to do now.

Comment: Well I just wrote up a game guide. It is a few paragraphs of writing I want to put in the app. But the amount of writing I have written can't fit on the screen without me putting in the ability to scroll through the text. It is very basic. Text on screen that NEEDS to have line breaks that can be scrolled through.

Comment: That doesn't help. I have a different TextView for each paragraph because if I don't there isn't a line break.

Comment: Hunter, as John mentioned above use the new line escape character in your string to force a line break (\n). If you still want multiple TextViews, just add more TextViews in the LinearLayout.

Comment: Look at my updated post if you really want to have multiple textviews.

Answer (score 0):

1- put the article you want to read in a .txt file
2- put it in assets Folder
3- add this to your activity.xml

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:maxLines = "10"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
```

4- and set this to your TextView in the activity

```
 TextView txtvue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txtvue.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        txtvue.setText( myReader("your.txt"));
```

5- to get paragraphs from the .txt file use this function

```
 public String myReader(String fileName) {
        AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open(fileName);
            int size = inputStream.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            inputStream.read(buffer);

            inputStream.close();

            // byte buffer into a string
            text = new String(buffer);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return text;
    }
```

Note: Please Do not call myReader(your.txt); in the main view thread it'll cause an error due to the lengthy process of reading text letters